# How to bind values to html <select> control using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have asp.net mvc Kendo grid. Grid rows has dropdowns, When user clicks on grid cell I am able to get Dropdown from below code but in that dropdown not able to bind values

```
var input = $("<select name='MinAcceptableName' id='MinAcceptableId'></select > ")
e.container.append(input);
input.focus();
```

I have a JavaScript function that should bind values to above control either **on code execution or on `<select>` click**

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetCodesList", "LookupCode")'
    var ddl = $('#MinAcceptableId');
    $('#MinAcceptableId').focus(function () {
        console.log("this is code value - " + code);

        $.post(url, {codeType: code, selectedValue: value }, function (response) {
            ddl.empty(); //clear if already data there
            ddl.append($('<option></option>').text("--Select--").val(""));
            alert("added default option to MinAcceptableName select");
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                ddl.append($('<option></option>').text(item.Description).val(item.CodeId));

            });
        });

        $('#MinAcceptableId').blur();
    })
```

From above code I am not able to bind values to dropdown(Dropdown empty). JavaScript function code seems is not executing all. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript">

function onEdit(e)
{   
      var input = $("<select  name='MName' data-value-update='MText' data-bind='text: MaText' id='MId'></select > ")
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var lookUpCodeUrl = '@Url.Action("GetCList", "LookupCode")';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: lookUpCodeUrl,
            })
                .success(function (responseData) {

                    $("#MId").empty();
                    $.each(responseData, function (i, v) {
                        $("#MId").append($('<option/>', {
                            value: v.CodeLovId,
                            text: v.Description
                        }));
                    })
                })

        }(jQuery));

        e.container.append(input);
        temp.remove();
        kendo.bind(e.container, e.model);
    }
}
</script>
```